# Display the array entry causing a test to fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-unittest

As part of a testing suite I have to check if a numpy array returned by a function is correct.
It is easy to do this check using `np.array_equal` which returns a boolean as to whether all of the array elements are the same.

If the test fails the error message is not particularly helpful for understanding what caused the failure.

```
import unittest
import numpy as np

class TestArray(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_values(self):
        x = np.array([1, 2])
        self.assertTrue(np.array_equal(x, [1, 3]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Test failure message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in test_values
    self.assertTrue(np.array_equal(x, [1, 3]))
AssertionError: False is not true
```

Is there a simple way to check the entries are equal, that displays the index and value of the first entry that is not equal? I want an error message like:

```
AssertionError: Arrays not equal at index 1 (2 != 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `np.array_equal` we could take the code and rewrite it, to add another check at the end

```
def array_equal(a1, a2):
    try:
        a1, a2 = asarray(a1), asarray(a2)
    except Exception:
        return False
    if a1.shape != a2.shape:
        return False
    eq = asarray(a1 == a2) # [ True False False True]
    if not bool(eq.all()):
        errors = [f"idx:{idx} ({vals[0]}!={vals[1]})"
                  for idx, vals in enumerate(zip(a1, a2))
                  if not eq[idx]]
        raise AssertionError("Arrays not equal " + " ".join(errors))
    return True

class TestArray(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_values(self):
        x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
        self.assertTrue(array_equal(x, [1, 2, 3, 1]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

> Gives `AssertionError: Arrays not equal idx:1 (1!=2) idx:2 (1!=3)`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was after. I was wondering if it is possible using just unittest and numpy functions too